# Jenkins JAVA_HOME 7 doesn't look like a JDK directory

Tags: java, jenkins, java-home

I have jenkins installed on a Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I'm trying to configure the jdk and when I type /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 in the JAVA_HOME field, Jenkins complains that it doesn't look like a JDK directory.
Anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67816/discussion-between-casablancais-and-jigar-joshi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is the location you are specifying is JRE not JDK (see comments since it doesn't have javac) also we couldn't find `javac` installed on System so just download fresh JDK and set JAVA_HOME point to there